# Multiple Files in formdata

Tags: javascript, ajax

a user can enter any number of files and datas related to file (eg., fileName, fileId, file). These datas need to be send to server through ajax POST call. My data sample

```
data = [ 
  {
    fileName = "test1",
    fileId = 1,
    file = document.getElementById('fileToUpload').files[0]
  },
  {
    fileName = "test2",
    fileId = 2,
    file = document.getElementById('fileToUpload').files[0]
  }
]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: What are trying to do ? What have you tried and what went wrong - Please add a reproducible code. Read how to ask a good question here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
var ins = document.getElementById('fileToUpload').files.length;
for (var x = 0; x < ins; x++) {
    data.push(
        { 
           fileName = "test" + x+1,
           fileId = x+1,
           file = document.getElementById('fileToUpload').files[x]});
        });
}
```